# Why I'm getting same data again and again how to handle data proplery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to offline support to my app, So what logic i want to do is first it check if there is cachedfeeds data if its there then it setFeeds to that data and that data will display from cache but it also fetches the API and get new data and after it get new data from API it deletes the old cachedfeeds data from storage and replace with this new data

In case if user opened the app first time and there is no feedcached then it normally give API fetched data to the user,

Currently my code is not replacing new API data to feedcached data i m getting  same data again and again from cache when i log the storedData how do i fix this?

```
  const [feeds, setFeeds] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [cached, setCached] = useState(false);

  const fetchallfeeds = async () => {
    try {
      if (!cached) {
        const storedData = storage.getString('cachedfeeds')
        if (storedData) {
          console.log(storedData)
          console.log('Fetching data from cache...');
          setFeeds(JSON.parse(storedData));
          setCached(true);
        }
      }
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/feeds/${page}`);
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log('Fetching data from API...');
      if (cached) {
        await storage.delete('cachedfeeds')
      }

      await storage.set('cachedfeeds', JSON.stringify(data));
      setFeeds(prevPosts => [...prevPosts, ...data])
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchallfeeds()
  }, [page, cached])
```

Comment: What api creates storage? If its a state management api like redux then it might have offline support built into it

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I'm not using redux but, I'm using react-native-mmkv

Answer (score -2):

fetchallfeeds was called whenever cached value changed, that’s the reason i infinit loop

Comment: Then what to do how to handle this properly? the page changes when i reach the end

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).